# Signed sum over labeled connected graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $\binom{n}{2}$ be the set of all subsets of $\{1,2,3, \ldots, n\}$ of size $2$ and let $C_n$ be the set of $E \subseteq C_n$ so that the graph $G$ with vertex set $\{1,2, 3, \ldots, n\}$ and edge set $E$ is connected.  Using generating function methods one can show that $$\sum_{E \in C_n} (-1)^{|E|} = (-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!.$$

For example, if $n=3$ then $$C_n = \{\{12,23\}, \{12, 13\}, \{13, 23\}, \{12, 13, 23\} \}$$ and then $$(-1)^2 + (-1)^2 + (-1)^2 + (-1)^3 = 2!.$$
Is there a more direct proof?  For example, a sign-reversing involution argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim holds for $n=1$. Assume that it holds for $n-1$. Then the graphs in which $n$ has exactly one edge and the rest of the graph is connected yield the result. The graphs in which $n$ has at least two edges, say to $u$ and $v$, come in groups of $2$, with or without the edge $uv$, and thus cancel.

Comment: Nice!  To elaborate a little: there are $n-1$ choices for where to connect $n$ to, so by the induction hypothesis the sum is $(-1)(n-1) \cdot (-1)^{n-1} (n-2)! = (-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!$ over the first set you describe.